# Can I refer to items within a LINQ result set by index?

Tags: linq, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to work with a LINQ result set of 4 tables retrieved with html agility pack. I'd like to process each one slightly differently by setting a variable for each (switch statement below), and then processing the rows within the table. The variable would ideally be the index for each of the tables in the set, `0` to `3`, and would be used in the switch statement and to select the rows. I haven't been able to locate the index property, but I see it used in situations such as `SelectChildNode`.

My question is can I refer to items within a LINQ result set by index? My "ideal scenario" is the last commented out line. Thanks in advance.

```
var ratingsChgs = from table in htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                  .SelectNodes("//table[@class='calendar-table']")
                  .Cast<HtmlNode>()
                  select table;    
String rtgChgType;

for (int ratingsChgTbl = 0; ratingsChgTbl < 4; ratingsChgTbl++)
{
    switch (ratingsChgTbl)
    {
        case 0:
            rtgChgType = "Upgrades";
            break;
        case 1:
            rtgChgType = "Downgrades";
            break;
        case 2:
            rtgChgType = "Coverage Initiated";
            break;
        case 3:
            rtgChgType = "Coverage Reit/ Price Tgt Changed";
            break;

    //This is what I'd like to do.
    var tblRowsByChgType = from row in ratingsChgs[ratingsChgTbl]
                           .SelectNodes("tr")
                           select row;
    //Processing of returned rows.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) does what you're asking for.  I don't recommend using it in your example, though, because [each time you call it, your initial LINQ query will be executed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).  The easy fix is to have ratingsChgs be a List or Array.

You can also refactor out the switch statement.  It is overkill when you only need to iterate through a list of items.  Here is a possible solution:

```
var ratingsChgs = from table in htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                  .SelectNodes("//table[@class='calendar-table']")
                  .Cast<HtmlNode>()
                  select table;
var rtgChgTypeNames = new List
                      {
                          "Upgrades",
                          "Downgrades",
                          "Coverage Initiated",
                          "Coverage Reit/ Price Tgt Changed"
                      };
var changeTypes = ratingsChgs.Zip(rtgChgTypeNames, (changeType, name) => new 
                                  { 
                                      Name = name,
                                      Rows = changeType.SelectNodes("tr")
                                  });
foreach( var changeType in changeTypes)
{
    var name = changeType.Name;
    var rows = changeType.Rows;
    //Processing of returned rows.
}
```

Also, why not store your rating change types in the HTML doc?  It seems odd to have table information defined in the business logic.

Comment: Thanks Risky. Those ratings changes are in the html, but not in the tables themselves. I thought this was easier than parsing out the known values.

Comment: Ah, okay. It just looked odd, but I don't know much about working with HTML.